# DOMDocument : How to get data as string from oboject

Tags: php, domdocument

i am using the following code :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($url);
$data = $doc->saveHTML();
preg_match_all("/$k1(.*?)$k2/s",$data,$matches);
```

and it's generating this error :

> Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in       /home/maruf10/public_html/dispatx.php on line 115

it will be helpful if anyone help to find the bug .
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
$data = $doc->saveHTML();
```

into

```
$data = (string)$doc->saveHTML();
```

it should work then.

Comment: another question : actually 
$doc->loadHTML($url);
this statement is not valid . loadHTML does not take a url as parameter.how can i load the html using url ??

Comment: well you should get the content with file_get_contents or curl and then pass the output into the loadhtml() method.